# Class not found when using spl_autoload_register

Tags: php

I've placed the spl_autoload_register function in my index.php (root directory) file: 
I'm using spl_autoload_register like the following:

```
spl_autoload_register(
   function($class) {
        include 'classes/' . $class . '.php';
    }
);
```

But when processing the form (/processing/form_process.php), I get the error:

> Fatal error: Class 'DBi' not found in G:\xampp\htdocs\critwild\processing\form_process.php on line 2`

On line 2, I'm creating the new DBi object (DBi.php from my classes dir), using $conn = new DBi;

The form action page is NOT in the same directory as the index.php (it's in /processing/form_process.php). When copying the spl_autoload_register command to the form processing page and changing the include path (to `'../classes/' . $class . '.php'`), the error goes away.

Would anyone have any ideas on how I could include it once in my index.php page, instead of copying it to multiple pages, if possible?

My current index.php page, includes header, footer, and content (right now only register.php) pages:

```
<?php 
include("layout/header.php");
spl_autoload_register(
function($class) {
        include 'classes/' . $class . '.php';
    }
);
$p_req = "register";
if ($p_req == "register") {
    include("content/register.php");
}
include("layout/footer.php");
?>
```

---

```
My directory structure:
[/]
 index.php

   [classes]
     DBi.php

   [processing]
     form_process.php

   [content]
     register.php
```

Comment: Put absolute path to the directory in the auto-load function in the first place, and if it's included properly, it will work properly. ie. `"/path/to/classes/". $class .".php"`

Comment: You can set an [`include_path`](http://php.net/include_path) or make your autoload function cwd agnostic using `include "$_SERVER[DOCUMENT_ROOT]/classes/".`. As for not having to redeclare it outside of your index script, just have it dispatch to the `form_process` script equivalently as to your `register` hook.

Answer (score 0):

Bah! I thought I read that spl_autoload_register only needed to be loaded once per session and it seems that I was mistaken. It needs to be included in each page that requires use of your class(s).